# How we to call the child page method from master page in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I have Implemented the Globalization in my Page. I have specified the Flags for changing one language to another.

When I click the Flag I am setting the Application`["LangId"]="1";` Now the content of the master page is refreshing but the content of the child page does not refresh. Because I have called setting the Language in every child Page load. According to the terminology Child page load fires first and after Master page load and the Click event. If I call the Language setting method in click event I will get the refreshed content.

My question is how we can call the child page method in master page button click event.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a property in your master.

```
public flag{get;set;}
```

And load it in page load. Then you can access that from child pages like this:

```
var flag=((MasterPage)Master).flag;
```

If you load your child pages this way, they will be refreshed whenever that property changes on MasterPage (if page is refreshed of course)

Comment: Or you could set the master page type using the [MasterType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/c8y19k6h(v=vs.100).aspx), avoiding the need for a cast.